# Unlock encrypted partions per user account with Bitlocker

Tags: windows, bitlocker, disk-encryption

I am using a Laptop and have encrypted the system partition, with Bitlocker, so that every user can use it after boot, which works. But I would also like to have multiple partitions (one per user), which get "auto-unlocked" once a specific user logs in. Lets say: CEO partition, software engineer partition, "some other user" partition. I want to keep the data encryped and private, too. It that possible?

Comment: Just looking into this with a VM.... additionally, you could also use EFS which has been a windows feature since XP (I think?)

Answer (score -1):

I would split the primary partition, so that you have the count of needed drives (C:, D:, E:). Then I would encrypt C: with BDE as the system drive. And I would do the same with the other two drives D: and E: but here as the "fixed data drives" (not as the operating system drive). In this case you can set the pin protector to unlock your drives (look for: "Configure use of passwords for fixed data drives" group policy). The user (and the administrator) can set than a password (pin) for the drives.

[Look here: Azure Group Policy](https://gpsearch.azurewebsites.net/#2602)

Comment: This is not what the question asked. Once a user unlocks a partition with his or her PIN or password, the partition is unlocked for everyone.